# flow augmentation in a directed network with the constraint edges with a common source must have the same flow

Tags: python, graph-theory, network-flow

I am currently trying to create a program that finds the maximum flow through a network under the constraint that edges with a common source node must have the same flow. It is that constraint that I am having trouble with.

Currently, I have the code to get all flow augmenting routes, but I am hesitant to code the augmentation because I can't figure out how to add in the constraint. I am thinking about maybe a backtracking algorithm that tries to assign flow using the Ford-Fulkerson method and then tries to adjust to fit the constraint.

So my code: 
There is a graph class that has as attributes all the vertices and edges as well as methods to get the incident edges to a vertex and the preceding edges to a vertex:

```
class WeightedEdge:
    def __init__(self, from_vertex, to_vertex, capacity):
        self.tail = from_vertex
        self.head = to_vertex
        self.capacity = capacity

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, vertices, edges, capacities):
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.edges = [WeightedEdge(edges[i][0], edges[i][1], capacities[i]) for i in range(len(edges))]

        self.__forward_list = {v : [] for v in vertices}
        self.__reverse_list = {v: [] for v in vertices}

        for i in range(len(edges)):
            self.__forward_list[edges[i][0]].append((edges[i][1], capacities[i]))
            self.__reverse_list[edges[i][1]].append((edges[i][0], capacities[i]))

    def out_edges(self, vertex):
        return [WeightedEdge(vertex, next_vertex, capacity) for (next_vertex, capacity) in self.__forward_list[vertex]]
    
    def in_edges(self, vertex):
        return [WeightedEdge(prev_vertex, vertex, capacity) for (prev_vertex, capacity) in self.__reverse_list[vertex]]
```

Each edge is an object that has a tail vertex attribute, a capacity attribute and a head vertex attribute.
So far this is my function that gets the flow augmenting routes:

```
def max_equal_split_flow(graph, source, sink):
    def find_augmenting_routes(vertex):
        route_buffer.append(vertex)
        if vertex == sink:
            flow_augmenting_routes.append([v for v in route_buffer])
            return
        else:
            out_edges = graph.out_edges(vertex)
            for edge in out_edges:
                find_augmenting_routes(edge.head)
                route_buffer.pop()
    flow_augmenting_routes = []
    route_buffer = []
    find_augmenting_routes(source)
    print(flow_augmenting_routes)
```

**TLDR: How can I find the maximum flow through a network when all edges that share a source node must have the same flow?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out!!! I was massively overcomplicating the problem.
This algorithm here finds the desired output:

It works by finding out how much you would divide an initial flow by once you had got to the current edge and storing that in a dictionary, and then works out using the stored capacities of all the edges, what the maximum initial flow would be.
For example:
[image: Example of my method to find maximum equal split flow]

Comment: Elegant and clever.  I am not certain that flow_split is needed.  The maximum flow divisor is an attribute of an edge, why not store it there?  When you need it, you have already done a lookup on the edge, why do another separate lookup again in flow_split?  Then, at the end you do another lookup on EVERY edge to calculate the minimum of x.  If you kept a running minimum as you go along, then all these lookups could be avoided.  I think these changes would double the speed of your algorithm.

Comment: BTW if you do want to keep flow_split for some reason, you can still gain a significant performance improvement in your second last line - instead of iterating over edges and then doing an expensive lookup for each edge, just iterate over flow_dict itself, the result will be the same but run much faster.

Comment: So turns out that one of the requirements for the project was that I was not allowed to add attributes to the edge and graph classes (this was a commission and the client did not tell me this until this morning). I will have a go at making it more efficient now, thanks so much for all of your help!

Comment: I have implemented the Nestor algorithm in PathFinder. ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/wiki/Flows )

Comment: I am honoured! <3

Comment: Do you have a real problem to test the implementation on?

Comment: What do you mean by real problem?

Comment: I assume that this algorithm is needed to solve a problem that models some real world situation.  I am intrigued to know what that might be.  I would also be interested to run my C++ implementation against a real world problem and check the result and compare the performance with your python implementation.

Comment: Oh no, it was just a school project, here are 4 graphs, write a function to find the equal split flow. however I can imagine a situation where you would be sending data packets through a network and even though you could send a large number of packets through a single edge (or whatever medium is being used) you may want to split it evenly across all edges to reduce having a single point of failure causing too many issues.

Comment: Well that was a waste of time and effort.

Comment: Suggest to your teacher that student time not be wasted on problems made up out of thin air.  Network routing protocols that adjust traffic when a failure occurs might be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you have an input that specifies the maximum flow through each edge.

The algorithm is then:

1. Because edges with a common source must have same actual, final flow the first step must be a little pre-processing to reduce the max flow at each edge to the minimum flow from the common source.
2. apply the standard maximum flow algorithm.
3. do a depth first search from the flow origin ( I assume there is just one ) until you find a node with unequal outflows.  Reduce the max flows on all edges from this node to the minimum flow assigned by the algorithm.  Re-apply the algorithm.

Repeat step 3 until no uneven flows remain.

=====================

Second algorithm:

1. Adjust capacity of every out edge to be equal to the minimum capacity of all out edges from the common vertex
2. Perform breadth first search through graph.  When an edge is added, set the flow through the edge the minimum of

- the flow into the source node divided by the number of exiting edges
- the edge capacity

3. When search is complete sum flows into destination node.

For reference, here is the C++ code I use for depth first searching using recursion

```
void cPathFinder::depthRecurse(int v)
{
    // record new node on the search
    myPred.push_back(v);

    // remember this node has been visted
    myPath[v] = 1;

    // look for new adjacent nodes
    for (int w : myGraph.adjacent(v))
        if (!myPath[w])
        {
            // search from new node
            depthRecurse(w);
        }
}
```

Here is the simplest sample graph that shows that adjusting the capacity of out edges is not sufficient to balance the actual outflows

```
format flows
g
l src a 210
l a b 200
l a c 200
l b d 500
l c d 500
s src
e d
```

( if this specification format is not immediately obvious it is [documented here](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/wiki/Flows) )

Node 'a' has two out edges, whose capacities have been adjusted to balance.  However the 'src' node does not supply sufficient flow to fill the edges so the output is

```
total flow 210
a   -- b capacity 200 used 10
a   -- c capacity 200 used 200
src -- a capacity 210 used 210
b   -- d capacity 500 used 10
c   -- d capacity 500 used 200
```

This suggests another algorithm #3:

1. Adjust capacity of every out edge to be equal to the minimum capacity of all out edges from the common vertex
2. Apply the standard maximum flow algorithm.
3. do a depth first search from the flow origin until you find a node with unequal outflows.  Re-allocate the flows so they balance.  Remove in-edges to node and make it a new flow source with flow equal to sum of removed in-edges
4. Apply maximum flow algorithm modified to handle multiple sources
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until all flows balance.

Applying step 3 and 4 to the previous example gives

```
format multiflows
g
l a1 b 105
l a2 c 105
l b d 500
l c d 500
s a1
s a2
e d

b -- d capacity 500 used 105
a1 -- b capacity 105 used 105
c -- d capacity 500 used 105
a2 -- c capacity 105 used 105
total flow 210.000000
```

which meets the requirements.

=================================

Here is the PathFinder implementation of Nestor's algorithm

```
 void cPathFinder::equiflows()
        {
            // source outflows
            int outlinkpercent = 100 / node(myStart).outdegree();
            for (auto &outlink : node(myStart).myLink)
                outlink.second.myValue = outlinkpercent;

            // function to call each time a node is visited in BFS
            myVisitor.set(
                [this](int v)
                {
                    static int X = INT_MAX;

                    if( v == myEnd ) {
                        // destination reached, report maximum flow
                        std::cout << "maximum flow is " << X << "\n";
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    // sum the inputs
                    int sumInput = 0;
                    for (auto &inlink : inlinks(v)) {
                        sumInput += inlink.second.myValue;
                    }

                    // node outflows
                    int outValue = sumInput / node(v).outdegree();
                    for (auto &outlink : node(v).myLink) {
                        outlink.second.myValue = outValue;

                        // check if this outflow reduces maximum flow through network
                        int x = outlink.second.myCost * 100 / outValue;
                        if( x < X )
                            X = x;
                    }

                });

            // do a breadth first search, updating flows as we go along
            breadth();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but just because they have the same capacity doesn't mean the same amount will flow through them, I think you are onto something though, what more do you want to know? If I can solve the problem mathematically first, just as a network flows question, then the coding is secondary.

Comment: Is it "edges with a common source must have same maximum flow" or  "edges with a common source must have same actual, final flow"

Comment: Same final flow, so if you have a vertex A, that is connected to B and C, if the flow into A is 10, then the flow along AB must be 5, and the flow along AC must be 5, the flows can be floats if necessary.

Comment: The issue with this though is that there is no minimum flow, how would I go about finding this?

Comment: Oh, I was misreading what you were saying, I have just re-read it and I think that I understand!

Comment: Do you a small example problem where step 3 is required?

Comment: I cant figure out how to implement part 3 of algorithm 1

Comment: Do you know how to DFS?

Comment: On pen and paper I do, however, my issue is that this isn't a tree, it is a network, and branches can be connected, eg source can be connected to vertex 1 and 2, and then they can both be connected to 3. So I have to take that into account when adjusting flow out of 3.

Comment: Doing a depth first search has nothing to do with whether or not the graph is a tree.  Using recursion it can be done in half a dozen lines of code.  I will post in my answer the C++ code that I use for the purpose

Comment: FYI I have added an option to calculate maximum flow from multiple sources to PathFinder ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/wiki/Flows )

Comment: Thank you for all your help, your contributions have been ensightful